# Use -ComObject Word.application without install Word

Tags: powershell, ms-word, com

I have a powershell script which use "-ComObject Word.Application". I would like to use this in a windows server but it doesn't have Word.
For now, when i execute , i have this error.

```
New-Object : La récupération de la fabrique de classes COM pour le composant avec le CLSID 
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} a échoué en raison de l'erreur 
suivante: 80040154 Classe non enregistrée
(Exception de HRESULT : 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
Au caractère E:\BELAIRREC\Scripts\PowerShell\Doc2PDF.ps1:27 : 16
+     $Wrd     = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], 
COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I think it's no doubt because Word is not installed.
Is there a way to use -ComObject Word.Application without install Word ?

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is no, that is not possible. You must install Word to use the `Word.Application` COM object.

Comment: The less short answer is DON'T DO THAT. Office is not designed to run on non-interactive sessions (e.g. in a server environment), and you're asking for a tremendous amount of headaches by attempting to do so. Use @boxdog's answer.

Comment: @Michael Gunter has a good point. At some point Office will toss up a message box asking for confirmation of something or throw some sort of error and nobody will ever see it because it has no user or display context on your server and nobody will see the message. From the outside it will just "hang".

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to look at the [OpenXML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), which is a free library from Microsoft that lets you manipulate Office documents without installing the Office products (though the SDK needs to be installed).  The [Open-XML-PowerTools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) is an open source collection of cmdlets that make working with the SDK easier.

Answer (score 1):

Any COM object you call must be installed on the computer.

There is a free Word viewer that you can download from Microsoft but I do not know if it has an exposed COM interface.