# How would I update an existing docx programmatically with an existing dotx template file without MS Word being installed?

Tags: python, powershell, ms-word, openxml, docx

I'm having some trouble trying to update an existing docx file (that has content in already) with an existing dotx template file which has nothing but a logo, font colour and font size etc.  I've managed to create a powershell script using an MS Word Com Object to do this very thing but unfortuntely if MS Word isnt installed then the script wont work.

Powershell Script:

```
    $word=New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $word2=New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $word.Visible=$false
    $word2.Visible=$false
    
    $path="C:\test_stuff\"
    $input_file = "C:\test_stuff\features.docx"
    $output_file = "C:\test_stuff\test_file.docx"
    
    try {
        $wordopen=$word.Documents.Open($input_file)
        $newdoc = Join-Path -Path $path -childPath "my_template.dotx"
        # Create new docx from template
        $wordopen2=$word2.Documents.Add($newdoc)
        #copy data from opened docx
        $range = $wordopen.Range()
        $copy = $range.Copy()
        # paste data to newly created docx
        $range2 = $wordopen2.Range()
        $range2.Paste($copy)
        # Save
        $wordopen2.SaveAs($output_file, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatDocumentDefault)
        $wordopen2.Close()
        $wordopen.Close()
    }
    catch { "An error occurred." }
```

Is there a way I can do this in Powershell or Python without having MS Word installed?

Comment: The com object Word.Application is not available without an installation of word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use -ComObject Word.application without install Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646343/use-comobject-word-application-without-install-word)